# Conditionally counting from a column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have some data stored in `df1`:

```
| id1 | id2      | product |
|-----|----------|---------|
| 1   | abc-2323 | Upload  |
| 1   | 234234   | Upload  |
| 1   | 43322    | Upload  |
| 2   | abc-449  | Upload  |
| 3   | abc-495  | Upload  |
| 3   | 432      | Upload  |
| 3   | 6543     | Upload  |
```

Per `id1` and `product`, I want to count the distinct `id2`s based on weather they begin with `abc-` or not. I have tried a conditional aggregation like this:

```
agg_data = (
    df1
    .groupby('id1', 'product')
    .agg(
       sf.when(~ sf.col('id2').like('abc-%'), sf.countDistinct('id2')).alias('id2_count_without_abc'),
       sf.when(sf.col('id2').like('abc-%'), sf.countDistinct('id2')).alias('is2_count_with_abc')
    )
)
```

However this errors out that `id2` is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. I'm unsure why I cannot do this conditional since simply `sf.countDistinct('id2')` would work by itself. E.g. No problem with this:

```
agg_data = (
    df1
    .groupby('id1', 'product')
    .agg(
       sf.countDistinct('id2').alias('id2_count_without_abc'),
       sf.countDistinct('id2').alias('is2_count_with_abc')
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `groupBy` you will get many rows per group. Since you can get one value per group for `countDistinct()`, you won't get error. But for when clause you can pass one value at a time but group will return multiple rows.

To get rid of this error you can select one value using `first()` or `last()` (This will return first/last value of corresponding group) and pass that to `when()` function.

But you need all the values of group for count calculations based on one condition. Below code should do the trick.

```
df1.groupby('id1', 'product') \
.agg(sf.collect_list('id2').alias('id2')) \
.withColumn('id2_count_with_abc', sf.size(sf.expr("filter(id2, i-> i like 'abc-%')"))) \
.withColumn('id2_count_without_abc', sf.abs(sf.size(sf.col('id2')) - sf.col('id2_count_with_abc'))) \
.drop('id2').show()


+---+-------+------------------+---------------------+
|id1|product|id2_count_with_abc|id2_count_without_abc|
+---+-------+------------------+---------------------+
|  2| Upload|                 1|                    0|
|  1| Upload|                 1|                    2|
|  3| Upload|                 1|                    2|
+---+-------+------------------+---------------------+
```